# API and HTTP flutter data

Tags: flutter, dart

How to Fix this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kku7k.png)
Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.

- 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
  await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');

Error: Property 'title' cannot be accessed on 'Post?' because it is potentially null.

- 'Post' is from 'package:networking/model/post.dart' ('lib/model/post.dart').
  Try accessing using ?. instead.
  return Text(snapshot.data.title);
  ^^^^^
  lib/model/post.dart:11:17: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'JsonCodec'.
- 'JsonCodec' is from 'dart:convert'.
  Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
  id: json['id'],

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Uri.parse() for parse url of api like

```
http.get(
          Uri.parse('${AppConfig.apiBaseUrl}country'),
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

`http` does not handle the URL strings directly starting from `http: 0.13.0`.

You need to use either.

```dart
http.get(Uri.https(AppConfig.apiBaseUrl, 'country'));
```

or

```dart
http.get(Uri.parse('${AppConfig.apiBaseUrl}country'));
```